# Is my plan for running cable 250ft to a subpanel OK?

Tags: subpanel, load, aluminum-wiring

Im running 2224 aluminum 250ft to a subpanel. I need two 15amp outlets. I plan on using 2224 and a subpanel. Is there a better option. Thank you !

Comment: The only real issue is voltage drop. Which is determined by total simultaneous load. According to [the Southwire Voltage Drop calculator](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop) you are good on 120V up to 24A before you hit a 3% issue. (Note: 3% is not an absolute rule, just a guide). 24A would actually be enough for **4** fully loaded (80% continuous) 15A receptacles (2 on each leg). TL;DR No problem. But explain the *full* plans - unusual to actually plan on such heavy wire to run a pair of 15A receptacles. As in: Is this likely to expand to additional uses?

Comment: 2224 is the smallest SER I can find locally. It's also pretty reasonable per foot, cheaper than four strands of #6 THWN2, while also being more capable. I can get 4444 but nobody local stocks it, and it's barely cheaper. OP is that your reasoning or is it something else?

Comment: CONDUIT! Make sure you run this in conduit. It'll cost more up front, but it will be far cheaper in the future should you ever need to repair or replace it. Also, conduit is less tasty to burrowing critters than plain cable insulation, so you're less likely to have to replace it due to hungry gophers or other.

Answer (score 6):

250 feet is too far to be entirely within a structure or otherwise above ground. SER can't go underground.  If you're undergrounding any of this, you'll need a buryable wire type such as MH feeder (however that has limits on use indoors, which can be cured by putting it inside conduit).

I think going with #2 aluminum is a great plan.

Since you only want 120V out there *right now*, it would be possible to pinch pennies by only using 3-wire cable.  However if you ever did anything more serious later, you'd regret the short-sightedness.

Since you only need two outlets (and I'm not sure if that means two circuits or not), one option is to skip the subpanel and its grounding rod requirement, and make it a "MWBC" or Multi-Wire Branch Circuit. The problem with this approach is you need to find a way to splice #2 aluminum to #12 copper, since a 20A breaker won't take #2 aluminum, and neither will common receptacles.  The cost of those six splices may be considerably more than the cost of the subpanel and ground rods.

Comment: My local electrical distributor stocks 2246 aluminum mobile home feeder cable, which can be direct buried or run in conduit. It might be a great choice here.

Comment: 2-2-4-6 might not might not be ideal for future-proofing since the undersized neutral may limit loads compared to 2-2-2-4. Although it's still plenty of headroom compared to the initial planned 15A loads.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the typical pricing of 2-2-2-4 being low, due to volume, and the length of run, and the non-competetitive price of other wire/cable options with adequate capacity for such a long run, that's probably the best choice, yes. Shop around and see what your local prices say, but it's commonly the best price for a long run, even where it's somewhat overkill.

Your sub-panel can be any ampacity equal to or larger than your feed breaker. Your feed breaker could be anything from a two-pole 15A (your stated need at the far end) on up to a two pole 90A (the limit of the wire) and choosing something like 30-50A would allow for possible additional load at little to no extra initial cost over a 15A two pole.

You'll need a set of grounding rods at the sub-panel location. Those connect to the ground of the case of the panel and the incoming ground from the house. The neutral at the sub-panel remains isolated from (not bonded to) ground there. It connects to the neutral from the house.